Can user files be uploaded via Google Drive API?
I have a web application (productivity application). I want to store user-generated content on Google Drive. But Google Drive API policies confused me.
https://developers.google.com/drive/api/terms
*The Drive API is not allowed for certain use cases without Google’s express prior written consent, including the following:
Backup of user or app content from a developer’s app or project to Drive.*
But
*The use of restricted scopes is allowed for certain situations, such as:
Platform-specific and web apps that provide local sync or automatic backup of users’ Drive files.*
Can I store user data (pdf, json, zip, special app extension) on the user's own Google Drive? I've seen web applications that do this. Do I need special permission from Google or is it free?
